# Connect event handler to TextField key event

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Suppose I have a `TextField` control and a key event handler:

```js
TextField {
    Keys.onPressed: console.log("key was pressed");
}
```

But what I want is to connect to `TextField` key event from outside it, without modifying the `TextField` control itself. Something like that:

```js
TextField {
    id: textField
}
Connections {
    target: textField
    Keys.onPressed: console.log("key was pressed");
}
```

It certainly does not work, but maybe there is some way to do that?

Comment: I guess you have some already written code and you cannot change it. I don't think that could be done. At least not *after*. Maybe you can intercept keys *before* they are caught from the inner handler.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `Keys.onPressed` is what's known as an [attached signal handler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#attached-properties-and-attached-signal-handlers).  Unlike most other things in QML, attached signal handlers (and attached properties) aren't valid outside of the object they live in.

Fortunately, there's an easy workaround: just add a new signal inside your `TextField` and listen to that instead:

```
TextField {
    id: textField

    // Add a new signal here
    signal keyPressed(var event)

    // Connect the existing signal to our new signal
    Keys.onPressed: keyPressed(event)
}

Connections {
    target: textField
    onKeyPressed: console.log("Key pressed", event.text)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MrEricSir, I know about signals and this workaround too. But I look for solution without modifying the `TextArea` control

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are multiple solutions depending on your use case:

1. Create a custom component which extends the `TextField` listening to the `Keys` events, as posted by @MrEricSir.
2. Use the property `forwardTo` of `Keys` object (https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qml-keys.html). The property `forwardTo` will send all events to the given list of `Item`: so, when a key event is triggered, **all** the specified items will emit that event.

```js
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Events Sample")

    TextField {
        id: textField
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        // Forward textField's key events to the following list of Items
        Keys.forwardTo: [itemEventsHandler1, itemEventsHandler2]
    }

    Item {
        id: itemEventsHandler1

        Keys.onPressed: {
            console.debug("itemEventsHandler1 | Event key: ", event.key)
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: itemEventsHandler2

        Keys.onPressed: {
            console.debug("itemEventsHandler2 | Event key: ", event.key)
        }
    }

}
```

If you type `abc` on the textField, the output is:

```
qml: itemEventsHandler1 | Event key:  65
qml: itemEventsHandler2 | Event key:  65
qml: itemEventsHandler1 | Event key:  66
qml: itemEventsHandler2 | Event key:  66
qml: itemEventsHandler1 | Event key:  67
qml: itemEventsHandler2 | Event key:  67
```

Let's now suppose that your `textField` is a property set afterwards. The same result can be achieved in this way:

```js
// The text field that will be set afterwards
property TextField textField

onTextFieldChanged: {
    // Safety check
    if(textField){
        // Forward textField's key events to the following list of Items
        textField.Keys.forwardTo = [itemEventsHandler1, itemEventsHandler2]
    }
}


Item {
    id: itemEventsHandler1

    Keys.onPressed: {
        console.debug("itemEventsHandler1 | Event key: ", event.key)
    }
}

Item {
    id: itemEventsHandler2

    Keys.onPressed: {
        console.debug("itemEventsHandler2 | Event key: ", event.key)
    }
}
```

Note that `Keys` events are emitted by the `Item` which is in focus (which in this case is the `TextField` if you are typing), so if another item has the focus, the events will not be forwarded.